# R: Repeat values of vector by values of different set of variables by group

Tags: r, list, repeat

I am trying to turn firm level data on the number of employees per pay level into individual level data that assign the pay to each of the number of employees within the pay band for each firm.
In doing so I want to repeat each pay level by the number of employees in each pay level.

My current data looks like this:

```
serno pay1 pay2 pay3 pay4 pay5 pay6
10001  0    1    0    1    1    8
10002  0    0    14  317  644  1610
10003  5    19  103  204  93    27
10004  0    5    49  124  403  927
```

Now I want:

```
serno Pay 
10001 pay2
10001 pay4
10001 pay6
.
.
10001 pay8
10002 pay3
10002 pay3
.
.
10002 pay6
.
.
```

I used the repeat and times code. Whilst this worked for turning the overall firm level data in individual level data in that I have created a list which equals firm_name times total_employees, it did not work for repeating the pay level times the employees per pay level for each workplace.

I have created a list with all employees per workplace:

```
serno <- rep(VOI_MQ_2011$serno, times = VOI_MQ_2011$employees_total, by=list(VOI_MQ_2011$serno))
```

When trying to do the same thing for the vector with the pay variales, it does not work:

```
pay <- rep(c(2.97, 6.72, 8.75, 11.50, 15.50, 27), times = c(VOI_MQ_2011$pay1, VOI_MQ_2011$pay2, VOI_MQ_2011$pay3, VOI_MQ_2011$pay4, VOI_MQ_2011$pay5, VOI_MQ_2011$pay6), by=list(VOI_MQ_2011$serno))
```

I have also tried the rep.int command:

```
pay <- rep.int(c(2.97, 6.72, 8.75, 11.50, 15.50, 27), times = c(VOI_MQ_2011$pay1, VOI_MQ_2011$pay2, VOI_MQ_2011$pay3, VOI_MQ_2011$pay4, VOI_MQ_2011$pay5, VOI_MQ_2011$pay6), by=list(VOI_MQ_2011$serno))
```

Error message for the rep() command:

> Error in rep(c(2.97, 6.72, 8.75,
>   11.5, 15.5, 27), times = c(VOI_MQ_2011$pay1,  :    invalid 'times' argument

Error message for the rep.int() command:

> Error in rep.int(c(2.97,
>   6.72, 8.75, 11.5, 15.5, 27), times = c(VOI_MQ_2011$pay1,  :    unused argument (by = list(VOI_MQ_2011$serno))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create the data:

```
dta <- read.table(text="serno pay1 pay2 pay3 pay4 pay5 pay6
10001  0    1    0    1    1    8
10002  0    0    14  317  644  1610
10003  5    19  103  204  93    27
10004  0    5    49  124  403  927", header=TRUE)
```

Now stack() the table and then rep() the rows of the data frame by the Freq value.

```
dta.st <- stack(dta[-1])
dta.df <- data.frame(serno=dta$serno, dta.st[, 2:1])
colnames(dta.df) <- c("serno", "pay", "Freq")
dta.df2 <- dta.df[rep(rownames(dta.df), dta.df$Freq), 1:2]
dta.df2 <- dta.df2[order(dta.df2$serno, dta.df2$pay), ]
rownames(dta.df2) <- NULL
head(dta.df2)
#   serno  pay
# 1 10001 pay2
# 2 10001 pay4
# 3 10001 pay5
# 4 10001 pay6
# 5 10001 pay6
# 6 10001 pay6
str(dta.df3)
# 'data.frame': 4555 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ serno: int  10001 10001 10001 10001 10001 10001 10001 10001 ...
#  $ pay  : Factor w/ 6 levels "pay1","pay2",..: 2 4 5 6 6 6 6 6 ...
```